Helm cm-push to push charts to helm repository
I am writing GitHub automation where the charts will be validated and then pushed to a chart museum which does not require any authentication mechanism. The workflow looks like:
name: Lint and Test Charts

on: pull_request

jobs:
  lint-test:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Set up Helm
        uses: azure/setup-helm@v4.2.0
        with:
          version: v3.14.4

      - uses: actions/setup-python@v5
        with:
          python-version: '3.x'
          check-latest: true

      - name: Set up chart-testing
        uses: helm/chart-testing-action@v2.6.1

      - name: Run chart-testing (list-changed)
        id: list-changed
        run: |
          changed=$(ct list-changed --config .github/ct.yaml)
          if [[ -n "$changed" ]]; then
            echo "changed=true" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
          fi

      - name: Run chart-testing (lint)
        if: steps.list-changed.outputs.changed == 'true'
        run: ct lint --config .github/ct.yaml

  release:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    needs:
      - lint-test
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Check if Helm ChartMuseum Push plugin is installed
        run: |
          if ! helm plugin list | grep cm-push; then
            helm plugin install https://github.com/chartmuseum/helm-push
          fi
            
      - name: Set up chart-testing
        uses: helm/chart-testing-action@v2.6.1

      - name: List changed charts

How to find out which chart is changed and push them using `
helm cm-push ".$CHANGED_CHARTS" http://chartmusem/ -f
Also is there a way to check if Check if Helm ChartMuseum Push plugin is installed by using some better approach not the tacky one that I have used

Note that OCI is currently a recommended approach, chartmuseum is rarely used. For cm plugin, you can use a specialized docker image, i.e. how we do here https://github.com/relizaio/dockerfile-collection/blob/master/helmpush/Dockerfile
For tracking changes we use a different approach via our SaaS Reliza Hub, you can see a sample here - https://github.com/relizaio/helm-charts/blob/master/.github/workflows/helmbuild.yml . You may also check our helm action for implementation details - https://github.com/relizaio/reliza-helm-action/blob/master/action.yaml
